# Bash Command using wildcard as an argument

Tags: bash, wildcard

```
x=rankings* && grep -A10 -P '^Ranked :$' $x | tail -n +2 > results$x
```

This is a command that I can't get to work no matter the approach and I haven't been able to find anything within 10+ searches of stack overflow.

Is there a way to feed a wildcard through as an argument to a single line of commands? I want to make a list of files based on existing files in the directory.

The closest I have gotten is

```
x=rankingsX.Y.Z && grep -A10 -P '^Ranked :$' $x | tail -n +2 > results$x
```

where X Y Z are some numbers, but this **hard-coding individually is the opposite of my objective** - a single line command(not script file) that searches and outputs specific text into files using the original names.

Comment: Generally speaking, asking for a "single-line command" is bad form, as it prioritizes terseness over readability. There's no reason you can't write `for x in rankings*` on one line, the body of your loop on a second, and `done` on a third at an interactive shell, and it makes the lives of anyone trying to follow what you're doing (including your future self!) much easier.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I suppose I ought to try using that part of the shell - assuming Konsole can do things like that?

Comment: There's no special terminal support needed -- if you write part of a compound command (that isn't syntactically complete in and of itself) and press enter, you'll see `> ` on the next line -- meaning that the shell is giving you a chance to add more / complete the already-started syntax. And if you want to split something that *could* be interpreted as syntactically valid on its own over multiple lines, putting a backslash on the end of one line will let you enter more on the next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A redirection only has one destination at a time; thus, an attempt to redirect to an expression which, when string-split and glob-expanded, results in more than one filename causes a "bad redirection" error.

What you want is `x` to have one value at a time, for each value the glob matches to -- which is to say that this is a job for a `for` loop.

```
for x in rankings*; do grep -A10 -P '^Ranked :$' "$x" | tail -n +2 >"results$x"; done
```

...which could also be written over multiple lines (even at an interactive shell), as in:

```
for x in rankings*; do
  grep -A10 -P '^Ranked :$' "$x" | tail -n +2 >"results$x"
done
```

Comment: This is a great explanation and exactly what I needed, thanks a lot!